# html style selector remains after webpack postcss processing

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I have added postcss loader with options to my vue js ui library project . I am using postcss loader so that when i import this npm package elsewhere the styles wont conflict. [Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#automatic-imports) CLI uses PostCSS internally.

my sample html:

```
<div id="navbackground ">
    <h5>Sample h5 text</h5>
</div>
```

one of my css classes e.g. mycolors.css has following content in it:

```
#navbackground {
  background: red;
}
h4{color:white}
```

configuration for postcss looks like below

```
  const prefixer = require('postcss-prefixer')

  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                prefixer({
                    prefix: 'mystyles-'
                })
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

And  the css file generated after running web pack build looks like below and it applies prefix.

```
#mystyles-navbackground {
  background: red;
}
h4{color:red}
```

AS you see from above h4 is NOT transformed with any prefix identifier and also stlyes(e.g. mystyles-navbackground) are not applied on html.

when i looked at the rendered html it has the same class id (navbackground) so it didn't apply the new style name (mystyles-navbackground)

```
  <div id="navbackground ">
     <h5>Sample h5 text</h5>
  </div>
```

Do i need to run another loader or plugin to apply the new prefixed style names to html ?

Comment: Which postcss loader are you using, I would recommend to use https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/

Comment: Vue CLI uses PostCSS internally. I updated the post with same.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1054
This might help me you, seems to be a known issue with autoprefix